# Elixir's mix format ignores line length option in umbrella project

Tags: elixir, code-formatting

I have an Elixir project  `.formatter.exs` file in my umbrella app's root that looks like this:

```
[
  line_length: 120,
  inputs: ["mix.exs", "config/*.exs"],
  subdirectories: ["apps/*"]
]
```

But as best I can tell, the `line_length` parameter is being ignored.

Given the following code, the longest line (whose length is 102 characters) is always being split into two lines (with the `when` clause wrapped to the new line):

```
defmodule SomeModule do
  def lookup_data(parameter1, parameter2) when is_integer(parameter1) and is_integer(parameter2) do
    :not_implemented
  end
end
```

In contrast, if I copy & paste the module into [the online Elixir formatter](https://elixirformatter.com) and set the line length option to 120, I get no changes to the text (as expected).

I must have screwed up the `.formatter.exs` somehow, but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [mix format docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/main/Mix.Tasks.Format.html), it notes that if your top-level `.formatter.exs` lists subdirectories (mine has `"apps/*"`), the rules from the top-level formatter won't be used in those subdirectories.

The solution was to edit `apps/[my_app]/.formatter.exs` (which had been auto-generated by `mix new` previously) with the line length parameter:

```
[
  line_length: 120
]
```